# Baking threeJS morphs

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm building with wonderful **API Three.JS** a sophisticated system of bones and morphs with a mesh created with Blender, everything works fine. But the morphs are giving me problems.

- Is there any way to get the new position of all the vertices of a mesh to the new position as the influence of a morphtarget?

That is, once the mesh has "experienced" deformation toward morphtarget might obtain the new position of each vertex.

Debugging the position of a cube called mesh: mesh.geometry.vertices.

I note that the position of the vertices does not change, just change the "morphTargetInfluences [01]" for example.

My intention is to keep the mesh with the influence of morphs, but without having to save the morph with the mesh.

My need arises for problems that arise when applying morphs more than 8 at a time on a mesh.

You can check the problem by applying more than eight morphs while [this example](https://www.stickmanventures.com/labs/demo/webgl-threejs-morph-target/)

Thank you!